# Sql concatenate result on case

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
Nomeutente|data      |Controllo
----------|----------|---------
utente1   |11-11-2016|prova1
utente1   |11-11-2016|prova4
utente1   |11-11-2016|prova3
utente2   |11-11-2016|ricontrollo
utente2   |11-11-2016|ricontrollo2
utente2   |11-11-2016|ricontrollo3
utente3   |11-11-2016|ricontrollo3
utente4   |11-11-2016|ricontrollo3
```

and with case i create a query like a pivot

```
Select
  BASE.data,
  Max(Case BASE.Nomeutente When 'utente1' Then base.controllo Else ''
  End) As utente1,
  Max(Case BASE.Nomeutente When 'utente2' Then base.controllo Else ''
  End) As utente2,
  Max(Case BASE.Nomeutente When 'utente3' Then base.controllo Else ''
  End) As utente3,
  Max(Case BASE.Nomeutente When 'utente4' Then base.controllo Else ''
  End) As utente4,
From
  (Select
    Nomeutente,
    data,
    controllo
  From PROVA) As BASE
Group By
  base.data
```

but I want in case that insert all controllo value like

```
Nomeutente|data      |Controllo
----------|----------|---------
utente1   |11-11-2016| prova1,prova4,prova3
utente2   |11-11-2016| ricontrollo,ricontrollo2,ricontrollo3
utente3   |11-11-2016| ricontrollo3
utente4   |11-11-2016| ricontrollo3
```

what kind of query can I create for make this on postgresql 7.4 ?

Comment: Postgres **7.4**? *Really*?

Comment: Postgres 7.4 is over 10 years old and has been unsupported for six years.  It is time to upgrade.

Comment: It's not my server and i can use this and the committer don't want to upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create aggregate (only once):

```
create aggregate textcat_all(
  basetype    = text,
  sfunc       = textcat,
  stype       = text,
  initcond    = ''
);
```

Then you can run:

```
select
  Nomeutente,
  "data",
  textcat_all(Controllo || ',') as Controllo
from
  <table_name>
group by
  Nomeutente, "data";
```

Recommeded reading:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-createaggregate.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: Tank so much it's work... I tried to insist on updating the db but are reluctant because even the software are outdated and there may be compatibility issues.

Comment: If I wanted to just put the different occurrences of the Controllo field? example if i have twice prova2 insert only one?

Comment: Try adding distinct: `textcat_all(distinct Controllo || ',')` (if I understood you correctly).